Struggling with installing Ubuntu on my 2015 Intel MacBook Air
This is where I'm at, I've got free space and have tried to click next via a MS-DOS partition, but it isn't allowing me!
Can someone please guide me through doing this/tell me what's wrong?
I'm trying to make a dual boot with macOS 12.7, I also have a dual boot of Windows 11 on my laptop. I did not have the option to make a dual boot, so I clicked Advanced options, also ask if you need more info.


Decided to install Arch instead, would recommend!
